# Split dom element with childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a web app that dynamically generates a document according to user's entries, the user can see the preview of his document right next to the form (The preview is updated each time the user answers a question). But I'm having trouble right now trying to figure out a way to switch from the ugly popup to a real PDF like preview, where the user can see in live his document with the same look then the output (the pdf).

I've tried many approaches like checking which child element is overflowing and moving it (the ones next to it) to the next element, but if the child element is too big then I will have like two lines on the first page, half on the other one etc...

I've thought about creating a canvas out of the popup (screenshot) but the app is going to be very greedy with the browser's resources and will kill the app's performances.

What's the best way to do it?

Is there a way in jquery to split this:

```
<span>
  <span>
    <span>
      Lorem impus
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

To this

```
<span>
  <span>
    <span>
      Lorem
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
<span>
  <span>
    <span>
      impus
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

But quickly and without impacting the apps performace?

Comment: `<div id="page">
<page size="A4">
</page>
</div>`

Comment: I wish it was that easy :)

Comment: why can't you use a pdf preview? Can generate pdf with javascript

Comment: Dude, You just made my day :D